# React.js: Confuse about `this` keyword context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I have one parent component and child component, which the parent include the child one. They have the same `counter` state:

```
import React from 'react';

class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            counter: 100
        }
    }
    render = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{this.state.counter}</h2>
                <button onClick={this.props.clickHandler.bind(this)}>Click</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            counter: 0
        }
    }
    addCounter = () => {
        this.setState({
            counter: ++this.state.counter
        })
    }
    render = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.counter}</h1>
                <Child clickHandler={this.addCounter} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I pass the `addCounter` handler from parent to the child one, and I think the context of the `addCounter` could change from parent to child through `bind` method, then when I click the button, the counter in child would increased instead of the parent counter state.

But the fact is, no matter the `clickHandler` bind `null` or `this`, the function only increase the parent's state counter.

So what's wrong with my thought, why the context doesn't change?

Comment: I misread your question initially.  Why are you making the Child rebind a passed in function?  That seems like a risky move.

Comment: @ctrlplusb thank you for your remind, certainly I would not do this in formal production. This is just a thought cross my mind, so I decide do some test and then find out it  not behavior as I expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using arrow functions. It is one of the purposes of arrow functions to maintain the "this" of the parent. [This should explain it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Change:

```
addCounter = () => { //your code}
```

To:

```
addCounter () {//your code}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have defined `addCounter` via the [ES6 arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), `this` is already implicitly bound to the parent object. You can bind the function again but this has no effect, as the binding is already in place.